# I can't find Django functions in the source code

Tags: django

I am writing a Django app and creating a custom user model. To do this I'm importing get_user_model from django.contrib.auth and this works fine. However, in order to understand things better, I'm trying to find this function in the Django source code but when I go to django.contrib.auth in the Git repo I can't find it.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

Comment: I can't tell you where you are going wrong, but the code is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is available in auth folder's `__init__.py` file: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py#L151](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L151)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has avoided further frustration. I tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the [`[source]` of the **`get_user_model`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model). This refers to a page that shows the [source code [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model):

> ```
> def get_user_model():
>     """
>     Return the User model that is active in this project.
>     """
>     try:
>         return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
>     except ValueError:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
>     except LookupError:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>             "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
>         )
> ```

In the source code directory, the `auth` is a directory, you can find the definition in the [**`__init__.py`** file [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L160).